# How to reduce the bass output from an amplifier

Tags: amplifier, speakers

I'm using a PAM 8403 mini digital amplifier along with a speaker I took from an old laptop to make a bluetooth speaker.

When I connect and play, everything works fine - except when I increase the volume. Then the speaker receives too much bass from the amplifier and starts to make noise.

When I try searching a solution for this, the only results I get are how to increase the bass, which is the opposite of what I want.

Is there anyway I can reduce the bass and make the speaker sound good?

Comment: An equalizer, parametric or graphical. Or just a straight-up high pass filter.

Comment: There'll probably be a coupling capacitor before the amplifier IC, making that a smaller value will attenuate low frequency content. Without having a schematic for your setup it's hard to recommend values.

Comment: "Design a first order high pass filter" at about 200Hz or maybe 400 Hz. The quoted term should allow you to find lots of helpful resources. But don't expect much from a poor little PAM8403.

Comment: You can use a pre-amp. , Between the audio source and your amp. ; Those have bass, treble and volume control on it. But be careful that you have to check impedances, it must be match with your circuits (the output of audio source and the input of pre-amp's impedance must be match, and, the output of the pre-amp. And input of amplifire's impedance  Must be match too, otherwise, you will lost some power of your system)

Comment: Reducing the bass isn't going to make it sound good, I'd just look for a better speaker.

Comment: That's odd: most folks complain of too *little* bass. Perhaps your complaint is the "rattling" that bass-passages induce? Is your speaker in an enclosure? An unenclosed speaker has more freedom-of-motion (especially at low frequency) than a speaker-in-a-box. You may find it makes less noise once enclosed, or only starts making noise at higher volume.